# Python Programming While Loop

Tags: python-3.4

Hi I'm new to python and programming in general. I am trying write a program that uses a while loop to add integers from 1 to the number entered. the program also has to give an error statement if the user enters a 0 or negative number. So far the integers add up and the error statement works but the program is not looping, it only asks the user to input a number one time. Please help. This is my source code so far.  Thanks

```
x = int(input("Enter a positive number not including zero:" ))

total = 0
n = 1


 while n <= x:
    total = total + n
    n = n + 1

# prints the total of integers up to number entered
    print("Sum of integers from 1 to number entered= ",total)

if x <= 0 or x == -x:
    print ("invalid entry")
```

Comment: You only need `if x <= 0:`... `x == -x` will always return false except for `0` I believe...

Comment: Have you considered `sum(range(n+1))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
op='y'
while op=='y':

        x = int(input("Enter a positive number not including zero:" ))

        total = 0
        n = 1

        if x > 0:

                while n <= x:
                        total = total + n
                        n = n + 1

                        # prints the total of integers up to number entered
                        print("Sum of integers from 1 to number entered= ",total)
        else:
                print ("invalid entry")


        op = raw_input("Are you want to continue this operation (y/n):" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the op entry made a difference

Answer (score 0):

Put your whole code this way

```
    done = False
    while not done:
        //your entire code here except the last 2 lines
        if x > 0:
            done = True
```